# several scrolling in RecyclerView causes to error xamarin.android

Tags: asynchronous, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I have a RecyclerView that contains cardViews as members and cardviews contains image views that there images come from urls with an async method.
It works but when i scroll it fast several times it causes to an unhandled error.
what shoud I do?

```
    public override async void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        var holder = viewHolder as MyViewHolder;

        holder.image.SetImageBitmap(null);

        holder.fname.Text = items[position].fname;
        holder.sname.Text = items[position].sname;
        holder.age.Text = items[position].age.ToString();
        holder.progressLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


        using (var imageBitmap = await GetImageBitmapFromUrl(items[position].imageURL))
        {
            var width = imageBitmap.Width;
            var height = imageBitmap.Height;

            var max = Math.Max(width, height);

            var scale = (double)holder.image.Width / max;

            var scaled = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int)(width * scale), (int)(height * scale), false);
            holder.image.SetImageBitmap(scaled);
        }

        holder.progressLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

    }

    private async Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I disposed the "scaled" variable after setting it as imageview bitmap

```
            var scaled = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int)(width * scale), (int)(height * scale), false);
            holder.image.SetImageBitmap(scaled);
            scaled.Dispose(); // here
```

Comment: I don't think you should set image as null, as in here:     holder.image.SetImageBitmap(null);

Comment: If I do not set it as null, the image of the previous view thet has been recycled will be shown during the loading of current image

Comment: I have not examine it. Just I think. So I will do your suggestion in the first time I can

Comment: You could use the Picasso library for Xamarin.Android https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso